# Repairing data source with joins to Excel without losing symbology?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, attribute-joins, excel, mxd

I have a set of MXD files, that do not use relative paths, and related data that have been copied to a new computer.  Normally it's not a big problem to repair the data sources in the project, but in this case some of the layers are joined to an Excel file.  When I try to repair the data sources any layer that is joined to an Excel file looses it's symbolization.

Has anyone run into this problem and figured out a fix?

Comment: Are you able to list the precise steps that someone could take to reproduce the symptoms that you describe?